# Detected beacons have same RSSI

Tags: android, kotlin, beacon, altbeacon, indoor-positioning-system

I'm using `AltBeacon` library to detect my beacons. They are place in rooms corners around 3-4m away from each other. What is pretty weird, is that they all return same RSSI value +/- 1. I wanted to do home experiments to understand how far am I from each beacon to detect my current position, but I didn't not thought that beacons will return same RSSI. How to get best accuracy in such a small room and is it normal for beacons to return same RSSI (I thought it should vary heavily).

Comment: This is not normal.  The value of RSSI is measured in dBm.  You typically see it drop from about -59 dBM at one meter to about -69 dBM at two meters, then to around -90 dBM at 25 meters.  What specific values do you see?  What Android device is this?  Do you have other Android devices to try?

Comment: @davidgyoung Okay, so I changed the Android device and it worked. Now I get different values - thanks. But, I guess that's okay if I get from one beacon approx. distastance 20m and then it drops to 10m and repeats (in reality, it's around 5m away, haha).

Answer (score 0):

Compare `dBm`, which is an absolute value - while `RSSI` is just a relative index.